# Get PHP to read directories with quotes in their names?

Tags: php, directory

I am using PHP 5's scandir($dir) function to iterate through a directory and print out an xml list of files. Only, when the directory has a single quote in the name, scandir returns no items! It doesn't return false (as it would if it failed) or generate warnings or errors - just empty. Any ideas?

```
$items = scandir(stripslashes($dir)); //strip slashes in case magic_quotes are on
if($items === false) die("scandir returned failure");
print_r($items)
```

Comment: your code worked fine for me (though last line is missing its ;) when I had a child directory with a single quote in its name on linux...are you trying this on windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested it on windows and it worked fine.
Try `echo $dir;` to make sure it's what you expect.

Also, use [`ini_set()`](http://www.php.net/ini_set) to make sure your error level is high enough:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
```

Comment: Actually, I'd recommend `echo stripslashes($dir);` — make sure that *scandir* is seeing what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the user executing the script has read permissions for the target directory?